# Ignore .svn when doing `diff -r`

Tags: svn, diff, recursive, ignore

`diff` has an option `--recursive` (`-r`) to do a comparison between two directories (the files inside them). Is there a way to make `diff` ignore certain sub-directories (eg: .svn)?

```
$ diff -r src1/ src2/
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Add `--exclude=".svn"` as an option like so:

```
$ diff -r --exclude=".svn" src1/ src2/
```

Comment: If you want to exclude multiple items just add another --exclude parameter.

Comment: If you don't want to type `--exclude` every time use `-x ".svn"`

Comment: --exclude option is also not working on mac os. -x ".svn" works well.

Comment: `--exclude` works well on macOS 10.15.2, /usr/bin/diff 2.8.1

Answer (score 16):

```
  diff --exclude=.svn ...
```